# Site gone missing from Google and no visitors in analytics

Tags: google

I've just noticed that since the 20th Juli, Google Analytics hasn't picked up on my visitors and my website is no longer on Google.com. Only subdirectories like `website.com/forum/`. I can't recall having changed anything, and my analytics code is still there.

Any idea why my site suddenly seems to block robots from checking my site?

Comment: I guess better place is to ask google this same question

Answer (score 4):

Get onto http://www.google.com/webmasters/ and validate your site on there. Look in particular under the section in Diagnostics under Malware and also Crawl Errors. If your site has picked up some hacker's malware then it will get blocked in Google and many modern browsers too. Also the crawl errors will show up problems such a robots.txt blocking indexing.

Secondly check that the world at large can actually see your site. Check there's no hosting or DNS issue that is preventing people form viewing your site. Easy way to do this is just ask a friend to view the site in his browser and see it loads ok.

Thirdly, have you made any big changes to your site in the last month. If so, try reversing them as they may have had an adverse affect.

Answer (score 1):

If any page from your website can be found in Google's search results you aren't banned. Also, no visitors doesn't mean crawlers aren't visiting your site. Under "Traffic Sources" click on "Search Engines" to see if Google is crawling your pages.

The most likely reason why you don't see any traffic in your Google Analytics report is because you aren't getting any traffic to your website. This makes sense if your pages are no longer being found or ranking well in Google and Google is your number one referrer.

If you search this site and Google you will find this is not uncommon. What you need to do is determine if your site violates Google's terms of service or offers low quality content. If so, you need to correct this. If not, your best bet is to continue to add quality content to your site and wait it out.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if your site has been banned, or perhaps robots.txt has vanished/become invalid.

google site:www.yoursite.com first to see if google still recognizes it.
If it doesn't and robots.txt is fine, you'll need to go through the google unbanning process.

Comment: If they can find any page from their website in the search results they aren't banned.